# Откатится ли транзакция в PDO, если код прервётся до commit'a?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Если код прервётся до пункта `commit`, откатится ли транзакция, при условии того, что у меня явно не прописано `rollBack`? Или же `RollBack` нужно прописывать по всех блоках `catch`?

```
try {
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $db->query($firstQuery);
    $db->someMethod(); //тут вылетает исключение
    //some code
    $dbh->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Ошибка БД';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Упссс, ошибочка';
}
```

Comment: При разрыве соединения с БД транзакция, начатая в нём, откатится. Так что ответ зависит от того, как у вас устроена работа с соединением.

Comment: @D-side, вопрос не в этом. С соединением у меня нормально всё, что если ситуация такая, в блоке трай я делаю запрос, а потом у меня вылетает исключение(никак не связанное с PDO и БД. Откатится в таком случае транзакция или нет? Т.е. нужно ли явно  писать rollBack ? . Подредактировал вопрос, что бы было понятнее.

Comment: А кто сказал, что соединение должно обязательно разрываться ненормально? Штатное отключение клиента тоже разрыв. Но видимо, прямой ответ на ваш вопрос -- "нет, не откатится", если вы говорите об откате при выходе из `try`/`catch`-конструкции. Но нет, прописывать `rollback` во всех `catch`-блоках тоже вряд ли обязательно.

Comment: @D-side , что то я не могу понять, вы говорите что "не откатится" и в тоже время, что rollback во всех блоках catch писать не нужно ?

Comment: Именно так. Потому что могут быть и другие способы, которые лучше доносят намерение. Не знаю конкретно в мире PHP, т. к. меня лично он несказанно раздражает и потому я его не изучал; но что на счёт вложить внутрь ещё один `try`/`catch`, который будет ловить **всё**, делать откат и кидать полученное исключение дальше, наружу, где уже по его типу выполнится более специфичный код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Транзакция не будет выполнена.

На ваш вопрос отвечает документация:

1) http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.transactions.php

> При завершении работы скрипта или при закрытии соединения, PDO
>   автоматически откатывает все незавершенные транзакции. Это делается,
>   чтобы предотвратить нарушения целостности базы данных в случаях, когда
>   скрипт неожиданно прерывает работу. Если вы явно не зафиксировали
>   изменения, предполагается, что что-то пошло не так. Поэтому откат
>   изменений - наиболее безопасный выход из ситуации.

Т.е. в вашем случае будет `авто-rollBack`, но стоит обратить внимание и на этот пункт:

2) http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.begintransaction.php

> Некоторые базы данных, включая MySQL, автоматически выполняют неявную
>   фиксацию, когда выражения языка описания данных (DDL), такие как DROP
>   TABLE или CREATE TABLE, находятся внутри транзакции. Неявная фиксация
>   предотвратит вам откат любых изменений, сделанных в этой транзакции.

Т.е. некоторые запросы могут вызвать `авто-commit`, и даже в случае провала, изменения останутся.